# String data doesn't return when I do that with a name containing _ in front of name

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuD57.png)

Plz let me know.. why it doesn't work here??

there says it is undefinied name.

Comment: Read this [article](https://flutteragency.com/create-private-variables-in-dart/)

Comment: your StoryBrain is class and you want access storyData inside other class. you must create instance to access it. and you dont use private variable for variable that you want access or create set-get function

Answer (score 0):

Define the function witin the `StoryBrain` class and call the function using `StoryBrain().getStory()`

Answer (score 0):

Firts, you define variable in a class, so you can't use it variable directly, you need an instance of class to call it variable.

Second, in dart `_` mean **private**.